# How to pass url to read png files in php

Tags: php

If I do

```
$dir = './';
$files = glob( $dir . '*.png');
foreach( $files as $file) {
    echo $file;
}
?>
```

And store the php file in the same folder as images I would get correct png files.

If I change location of php file How can I read png files located in other folder?

If I do

```
$dir = 'www.site.com/content/images';
$files = glob( $dir . '*.png');
foreach( $files as $file) {
    echo $file;
}
```

it does not display anything, is it necessary to the php file with code to be in the same folder of images?

Comment: you can try `$dir = '../other_folder';` or `$dir = '../../another_folder';` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't add `"www.site.com"` to path. You should use absolute path from the root of your server (beginning with `"/"`: `/content/images`) or relative path from current location of php script (`content/images`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are in fact trying to retrieve files on a remote server, look at this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php